# How can I print the next line to the current line provided they start with certain words?

Tags: python

I want to print the next line on the current line provided the current line starts with `"This"` and the next line starts with `"That"` of a file and write it back to the same file. How can I achieve this?

Note: I have some other lines in my file that I want to maintain as they are.

```
prev = ''
with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('This') and prev.startswith('That'):
        # Attach 'That' line with 'This' line
        prev = line
#Once done, write back to myfile.txt
```

INPUT:

```
Foo
This is my current line
That is my next line
Bar
```

OUTPUT:

```
Foo
This is my current line That is my next line
Bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to store the first and second line into 2 variables (`prev`, `cur`) outside of the for loop first before checking whether the first start with "This" and the second start with "That"

**Edit:**  I have edited my answer so that it can be used on files with multiple lines. In the case of multiple lines, you probably want to store the file lines into a list of string `lines` instead of using 1 or 2 variables. After storing the file content into a list, you can iterate through the file lines using a while loop. I use while loop instead of for since it gives you more freedom when navigating the array index.

```
lines = []
with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', ''))

with open("myfile.txt", 'w') as f:
    length = len(lines)
    i = 0
    while i < length - 1:
        if lines[i].startswith('This') and lines[i + 1].startswith('That'):
            f.write(lines[i] + ' ' + lines[i + 1] + '\n')
            i += 1 # skip the next line because it is concated with the current line
        else:
            f.write(lines[i] + '\n')
        i += 1

    # when the last line doesn't concat with its previous line
    if i < length:
        f.write(lines[i] + '\n')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! but what if I want to maintain the other lines in my file, here it only prints the "That" line in my file.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You are right, I can only see the last "That" line in my file.

Comment: @AlyssaAlex I have updated my answer so that it can work on multiple lines. Let me know if it is the output you expected.

Answer (score 0):

We want to attach lines that don't start with `This` directly to the output. Lines that do start with `This` need to be deferred until you get a `That` or not. In the former case, you strip out the newline between them, in the latter you attach both as-is.

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith('That') and index and lines[index - 1].startswith('This'):
        lines[index - 1] = lines[index - 1].replace('\n', ' ')

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

All you need to do is remove the newline characters: `writelines` won't insert any new ones for you.

While I've chosen to read the entire file into memory, you don't need to do this. A fairly standard approach would be to open a temporary file, write to it on the fly line-by-line, and then move it to replace the input file. The details of how to do that can already be found on SO.

Comment: I get this error: for index, line in lines:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    new_lines = []
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
        if idx > 0:
            if line.startswith('This') and lines[idx - 1].startswith('That'):
                new_lines.pop()
                new_lines.append('{} {}'.format(line, lines[idx - 1]))
            else:
                new_lines.append(line)
        else:
            new_lines.append(line)

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in new_lines:
        f.write(line + '\n')
```

myfile.txt (before)

```
afdfsdfdf dfsdfsdfs
That is my next line
This is my current line
sadgsdfg sadfgsgdfg
dfgdfgdfgdfgd
dfgdfgdfgdfgdf
That is my next line
sdftgertgertge
This is my current line
srgegergegyb  dfgtyrtyrty
That is my next line
This is my current line
eferer erwer
```

myfile.txt (after)

```
afdfsdfdf dfsdfsdfs
This is my current line That is my next line
sadgsdfg sadfgsgdfg
dfgdfgdfgdfgd
dfgdfgdfgdfgdf
That is my next line
sdftgertgertge
This is my current line
srgegergegyb  dfgtyrtyrty
This is my current line That is my next line
eferer erwer
```